# Simplifying $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{20}(k+4)\binom{23-k}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

In trying to simplify my answer to a problem posted recently, I am trying to show that
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{20}(k+4)\binom{23-k}{3}=8\binom{24}{4}$.

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{23-k}{3}=\binom{24}{4}$, but how can I simplify $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{20}k\binom{23-k}{3}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Note that
$$
4 + k=\pars{k - 20} + 24 = 24 - \pars{20 - k}
$$

> \begin{align}
> &\sum_{k = 0}^{20}\pars{k + 4}{23 - k \choose 3}
> ={1 \over 6}\sum_{k = 0}^{20}\pars{23 - k}\pars{22 - k}\pars{21 - k}
> \bracks{24 - \pars{20 - k}}
> \\[3mm]&=4\sum_{k = 0}^{20}\pars{23 - k}\pars{22 - k}\pars{21 - k}
> -{1 \over 6}\sum_{k = 0}^{20}\pars{23 - k}\pars{22 - k}\pars{21 - k}\pars{20 - k}
> \end{align}

Lets consider
$\ds{\fermi\pars{x}\equiv\sum_{k = 0}^{20}x^{23 - k}
=x^{23}\,{x^{-21} - 1 \over x^{-1} - 1} = {x^{3} - x^{24} \over 1 - x}}$

> Then,
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{20}\pars{k + 4}{23 - k \choose 3}}=
> \lim_{x \to 1}\bracks{%
> 4\fermi'''\pars{x} - {1 \over 6}\,\fermi^{\tt\pars{IV}}\pars{x}}
> \\[3mm]&=4 \times 63756 - {1 \over 6}\times 1020096
> =255024 - 170016 = \color{#66f}{\large 85008}
> \end{align}

Note that ( with $\ds{x \equiv 1 + \epsilon}$ ):
\begin{align}
&{x^{3} - x^{24} \over 1 - x}
={\pars{1 + \epsilon}^{24} - \pars{1 + \epsilon}^{3} \over \epsilon}
={1 \over \epsilon}\sum_{k = 0}^{24}{24 \choose k}\epsilon^{k}
-{1 \over \epsilon}\sum_{k = 0}^{3}{3 \choose k}\epsilon^{k}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{k = 1}^{24}{24 \choose k}\epsilon^{k - 1}
-\sum_{k = 1}^{3}{3 \choose k}\epsilon^{k - 1}
\\[3mm]&=\bracks{{24 \choose 1} + {24 \choose 2}\epsilon 
+{24 \choose 3}\epsilon^{2} + \color{#c00000}{{24 \choose 4}\epsilon^{3}}
+\color{#c00000}{{24 \choose 5}\epsilon^{4}} + \cdots}
-\bracks{{3 \choose 1} + {3 \choose 2}\epsilon 
+{3 \choose 3}\epsilon^{2}}
\end{align}

> such that
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{20}\pars{k + 4}{23 - k \choose 3}}=
> 4\bracks{{24 \choose 4}6} - {1 \over 6}\,\bracks{{24 \choose 5}24}
> =\color{#66f}{\large24{24 \choose 4} - 4{24 \choose 5}}
> \\[3mm]&= {\tt 85008}
> \end{align}

Comment: Just curious, what is with defining all those new commands?  You don't even use all of them...  (for example, $\+$)

Answer (score 2):

Maple gives
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{m+n-k}{m}
  =\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{(m+1)(m+2)}\binom{m+n-1}{m}\ ,$$
which can be checked by induction if you wish.  So your sum becomes
$$4\binom{24}{4}+\frac{23\times24}{4\times5}\binom{22}{3}
  =4\binom{24}{4}
    +\frac{23\times24}{4\times5}\frac{4\times20}{23\times24}\binom{24}{4}
  =8\binom{24}{4}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

So you want to prove $$\sum^{20}_{k=1}k\binom{23-k}{3}=4\binom{24}{4}\color{red}{=\binom{24}{5}}.$$

With that note, it's easy to come up with a combinatorial argument: How many ways to choose $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_5$ out of $\{1,2,\dots,24\}$?

$a_2$ can only be in $\{2,\dots, 21\}$. For $a_2=k+1\in\{2,\dots,21\}$, there's $k$ choices of $a_1$ and $\binom{23-k}{3}$ choices of $(a_3,a_4,a_5)$. The equality follows.

Comment: This is a nice argument!